# Flutter Errors when recently upgraded

Tags: gradle, flutter, dart

I was getting some weird flutter errors so i googled them and was told to upgrade flutter which didnt seem to help. I didn't touch any of these files, is this a bug? It was working fine a little bit ago.
I've tried flutter clean, flutter upgrade, flutter doctor and flutter pub cache repair
Here's flutter doctor:

```
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.2)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

```
Compiler message:
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:273:8: Error: The method 'FlushbarRoute.install' has more required arguments than those of overridden method 'OverlayRoute.install'.
  void install(OverlayEntry insertionPoint) {
       ^
../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:40:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('install').
  void install() {
       ^

Compiler message:
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:273:8: Error: The method 'FlushbarRoute.install' has more required arguments than those of overridden method 'OverlayRoute.install'.
  void install(OverlayEntry insertionPoint) {
       ^
../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:40:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('install').
  void install() {
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:281:18: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    super.install(insertionPoint);
                 ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:281:18: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    super.install(insertionPoint);
                 ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\-----\Documents\Flutt\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 833

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\-----\Documents\Flutt\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1'''../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:281:18: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    super.install(insertionPoint);
                 ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart:281:18: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    super.install(insertionPoint);
                 ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\-----\Documents\Flutt\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 833

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\-----\Documents\Flutt\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case the suggested edit to pubspec.yaml caused a version collision with one of the dependencies.
I just added a reference to a stable old version of flushbar in the dependencies section in pubspec.yaml

```
    dependencies:
        flushbar: 1.9.1
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to have been caused by flushbar_route plugin.

Try editing **flushbar-1.9.1/lib/flushbar_route.dart** which is located at

> "%YOURFLUTTERPATH% .pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flushbar-1.9.1\lib\flushbar_route.dart"

```
Line 273
void install() {

And line 281
super.install();
```

or the second fix is putting the line below in your pubspec.yaml file

```
flushbar:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/valterh4ck3r/flushbar
      ref: master
```

Source : Check [this](https://github.com/AndreHaueisen/flushbar/issues/113) for more .

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be (in very rare case) unstable plugins or flutter.

I suggest you shift to stable flutter channel (if on dev or beta)

```
flutter channel stable
```

and apply flutter upgrade

```
flutter upgrade
```

Here even though you are writing upgrade, you can always get the stable latest release. This solve my case. Hope this helps.